# axios baseUrl not working in react when using process.env

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have an axios helper file with a baseURL set in my react project. I have been told to remove the hard coded url and use process.env instead, but when I do this the requests no longer work for fetching the data and I get back a 404 GET error in my app.

```
import axios from "axios";

// axios.defaults.baseURL = "https://example-app-name.com";
axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL;

export default axios;
```

.env file in the root of my project looks like this - I am thinking maybe it cant find the .env file, I did install the dotenv library.

```
REACT_APP_BASE_URL=https://example-app-name.com
```

I get these errors

```
GET https://example-app-name.com 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to make sure that `dotenv` is imported wherever you're using the environment variables. Or if you're using Webpack you can load it in the plugins part of your Webpack config.

`const Dotenv = require("dotenv-webpack");`

In `webpack.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
plugins: [
  new Dotenv(),
  ],
}
```

[Here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) is a link that talks more about environment variable in React.

Answer (score 2):

When you modify a `.env` file, you need to restart the React environment.

1. Stop the React server.
2. Add the following line to your `.env` file :

   `REACT_APP_BASE_URL="https://example-app-name.com"`
3. Be sure to import **dotenv** where you use the REACT_APP_BASE_URL variable: `require('dotenv').config()`
4. `npm start` OR `yarn start`

Comment: I believe that if he uses create-react-app there is no need to import dotenv

Comment: Do we know if he is using create-react-app?

Comment: Im not using create-react-app, ive setup the project for the first time using webpack. I wasnt aware I needed to require the dotenv file as it does it automatically in cra. I am now getting another error I need to fix after requiring dotenv
ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js

Comment: yes I needed to require the env, I have mostly been using cra so webpack was tripping me up